# conversion of java input file to avro

Tags: java, generics, avro

I am trying to code for my project, where I need to convert a file which user will input and i need to convert this input file into avro file. The input file need to be coded in java programming.

The example of the input file is as follows.

```
:Temperature{
format: "temperature\ngeographicCoordinate"
temperature:int
geographicCoordinate:GeographicCoordinate{
    latitude:int
    longitude:int
    format:"latitude longitude"
}
}
```

The output avro file should be like below :

```
{   
"namespace": "org.input.data.temperature",
"type":"record",
"name":"Temperature",
"fields":[
    {
        "name":"temperature",
        "type":"int"
    },
    {
        "name":"geographicCoordinate",
        "type":
            {
                "namespace": "org.input.data.temperature",
                "type":"record",
                "name":"GeographicCoordinate",
                "fields":[{
                    "name":"latitude",
                    "type":"int"
                    },
                    {
                    "name":"longitude",
                    "type":"int"
                    }
                ]
            }
    }
]
}
```

I have few questions now.
1. How I make a generic input file, means the input can consist of any input like matrix, temperatures, complex number, Fourier series etc
2. How i code this?

Any help would really appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't see any java in there!? Could you be a bit more specific, please.

Comment: Maybe are you looking for [JSON](http://www.json.org/)?

Comment: @Dawnkeeper The coding has to do in Java, which transform the input file into the output file.

Comment: @Alessandro Yes it looks like JSON, but the output file is AVRO file right? 
Is it possible to convert the input file into the desired output file, with the help of JSON?

Comment: I have never used AVRO but according to the official documentation there is a specific class which will grant you to read an AVRO's formatted file. After that, you can serialize the object that you have read to a JSON's file using one of the available Java json's java library. Maybe you can use this: http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Comment: @Alessandro: Thanks for your reply. Here I am trying to create an AVRO file with the input file. If i will have AVRO file then I can use JSON right.Reading AVRO is second step.
First step here is to make AVRO from the input file, and here I am stuck. How i code generically that can include all sort of input, which could be anything like matrix, complex numbers, temperatures etc 
I really appreciate your reply. Please do help me if you can :)

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't understood really well what you mean when you say: "Here I am trying to create an AVRO file with the input file". Can you modify your post in order to explain what's exactly the input file format?

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia : is it clear now?

Comment: I think that you need to write your own parser in order to manage everything. Define a specific grammar (how your files should be structured) and after that you can write a simple parser that is able to read the input file and interpret it.

Comment: Yes you are right.I need help in writing that parser :(
I have no idea how to write it.

Comment: Look at this one: https://github.com/abailly/jparsec

Comment: I need more help. I am unable to do it.